# insert value into input tag from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have written a chrome extension which can successfully insert value into input tags on many pages by simple jquery code

```
$("#myId").val('myvalue');`
```

except [this page](https://login.freecharge.in/login?callbackurl=https://checkout.freecharge.in/payment)`

I have tried using javascript jquery but nothing works, Though chromes built in autofill  and [autofill extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en) can insert value efficiently.

From my chrome extension I want to insert value into these two input ID's "#loginEmailMobile" and "#clientpassword" . When I use .val() method it shows the value there but seems like floating. And don't work when I click on sign in. So how I can make it work? Please help.

Comment: Seems like you're relying on jQuery to be loaded on the page.
Did you try pure JavaScript? What happens when you do something like `document.getElementById('loginEmailMobile').value = 'email@company.com';`?

Comment: It just add a value attribute in the html. but don't show anything on input box.

Answer (score 1):

The page is listening for keyboard events to update the UI as well, your method is only changing the .value property. If you want the page to "know" something changed, you should send a keyboard event to the inputs as well. The AutoFill extension seems to do this by calling `someelement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` on the inputs, which seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Is the url permissions and schemes set for the website it is not working for?

Comment: I believe no issue with permission so error in console log. Code executes successfully and value shows floating over input box.